# MongoDB match documents with elements inside an array of nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like the following, and the target is to delete each document which matches to it's `items.fruits.color` AND `items.fruits.type`
The problem is, I need to find the fruit which has both conditions together.

Also, if the `items` key is empty, i need to select that document

This is the state of my aggregation:

```
{
    type: "x"
    color: "red"
    items => [
        {
          item_id: 6   
          fruits: [
                {
                    color: "red",
                    type: "x"
                },
                {
                    color: "red",
                    type: "y"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            item_id: 7   
            fruits: [
                {
                    color: "orange",
                    ref_id: "h"
                },
                {
                    color: "green",
                    ref_id: "x"
                }
            ]
        }
     ]
},{
    
    type: "o"
    color: "red"
    items => []

},{
    
    type: "w"
    color: "red"
    items => [
        {
            fruits: [
                {
                    type: "w",
                    color: "black"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So the first document is invalid, because attributes of `items[fruits][0]` is exactly match.

But the second one is valid, because the items array is empty.

The third one is also valid because there is no matching fruit's inside it's items.

The last query i tried was:

```
$match: {
   "items.fruits": {
      $not: {
          $elemMatch: {
              color: "$color",
              type: "$type"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

But it's not working. instead it's showing all documents. (I think it's because the $color statement is not recognized as a variable)

Comment: Dot notation transparently traverses arrays. Add the queries you tried so far and results they produced.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match on any document that does NOT have the fruit with a given color and type, this should work:

```
[{$match: {
   "items.fruits": {
      $not: {
          $elemMatch: {
              color: "red",
              type: "x"
          }
      }
  }
}}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. This stage will search in fruits and find one fruit with same color, then search again in all fruits and find another one(or maybe the same) with same type. 

But i need a stage to search in fruits and find Exactly one fruit, with same type and same color. not two difference fruits. That where the problem begin :(

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. I edited my answer above to reflect that.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can i replace the "red" with value of the color attribute? `             color: "$color"` seems not working

Comment: Can you? please

Answer (score 1):

I've headed in another direction.  I think this will get you started and you can add other $project or $group stages to get the final results in the format you need.

```
[
{$unwind: {
  path: "$items"
}}, 
{$unwind: {
  path: "$items.fruits"
}}, 
{$addFields: {
  "items.fruits.isAMatch": 
    { $and: [
      {$eq: ["$items.fruits.type", "$type"] },
      {$eq: ["$items.fruits.color", "$color"] }
      ]
    }
}}, 
{$group: {
  _id: 
    {"id": "$_id",
    "itemid": "$items.item_id"
  },
  type: {$first: "$type"},
  color: {$first: "$color"},
  fruits: { $push: "$items.fruits" }
}}, {}]
```

The first stage unwinds the items array.  The second stage unwinds the fruits array.  The third stage checks to see if the fruit and color match and creates a new field named `isAMatch` to indicate whether they do.  The final stage groups the documents back together based on the _id and the items.item_id.  The documents resemble the originals, but they have added fields in the fruits array objects indicating whether they were a match.